# Не срабатывает атрибут data

Tags: jquery

```
btnSave.parents('.for-clone').attr('data-dep-id', data.id);
btnSave.parents('.for-clone').data('dep-id', data.id);
```

Первый вариант работает, второй нет!

Проблема выражается в том, что второй вариант не обновляет значение атрибута `data-dep-id` у выбранного элемента.

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что он не работает ? Что возвращает `btnSave.parents('.for-clone').data('dep-id');` после выполнения _только_ второй строчки?

Comment: Потому что не заносит значение в аттрибут data-dep-id

Comment: А я вам говорю, что `.data()` работает ровно так как должен: https://jsfiddle.net/a19ed8nr/ . На самом деле, `.data` не меняет значение атрибута, а обновляет значение во внутреннем хранилище.

Comment: И это не первый раз уже сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой,которая решается заменой data на attr

Comment: В приведенном вами коде никакой проблемы нет (смотрите мой фидл выше). Просто нужно четко понимать для чего нужен метод `.data`, а для чего `.attr`

Comment: То есть задать значенеие data-dep-id  с помощью data у меня не получится?

Comment: Задать атрибут `data-dep-id` с помощью `.data` у вас не получится. Но `.data` нужен **не для задания атрибута** а для сохранения значений. Если нужно работать именно с атрибутом используйте `.attr`

Comment: Действительно вывел в console log значение и все нормально. Спасибо не знал что data так работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) вовсе не занимается обновлением атрибутов тегов, как вам, почему-то кажется. Вместо этого, он сохраняет некоторое значение, привязанное к DOM элементу *в своем хранилище*. В качестве первоначального значения берется содержимое `data-` атрибута.

Убедиться, что метод `.data` действительно работает можно, например, так:

```
$('#test').data('asd-qwe', 'Test String');
console.log($('#test').data('asd-qwe')); // Выведет "Test String"
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a19ed8nr/) с примером.

А если вам действительно нужно *изменять значения* `data-` атрибутов, используйте метод [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).