# Записать значение в data-атрибут

Tags: jquery

Добрый день. Движок использует такой метод записи значений в блоки:

```
$(".rating").html(data.fullrating);
```

И именно пишется `data.fullrating`, просто `fullrating` не запишется.
Суть в том, что мне нужно записать это значение в `data-percent="вот сюда"`, который на классе `.rating`.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как записать это значение в data-атрибудт через jquery?

Comment: `$(".rating").attr('data-percent', data.fullrating);` через `data` не рекомендую, непрозрачно работает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не срабатывает аттрибут data](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488900/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82-data)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('body').data('percent', "вот сюда значение ");
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/