# Не меняются вывод атрибута data элемента при повторном вызове функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $("#original_items li").each(function(e){
        var item = jQuery(this);
        console.log("---" + item.data('id'));
    });
});
```

Сответственно есть некий набор элементов `li` с атрибутами id.

Нажимаем кнопку TEST и видим в консоли список всех id. Все работает и все замечательно. Но если мы меняем при помощи скрипта один из id на новый, то после этого при нажатии кнопки отобразится старый ID. Как с этим бороться и почему это происходит?

Пример снизу. Жмем cons - видим в консоли 1,2,3,4,5 Жмем change id - меняем айди второго элемента на 999. Снова жмем cons - повторяется предыдущий вывод. 
При этом нажав вначале change id и потом cons вы убедитесь, что id меняется и код рабочий

UPD:
если заменить `item.data('id')` на `item.attr('data-id')` или выводить через `.dataset.id` то данные считываются верно. Это может решить проблему, но интересно понять, в чем причина такого поведения.

UPD2:
Как я понимаю функция jQuery.data сохраняет данные об объекте в jQuery.cache и при последующем вызове данные берутся именно оттуда. То есть поведение понятно, но не понятно, для чего это делается.

```js
$("#log").click(function(){
    $("#original_items li").each(function(e){
        var item = $(this);
        console.log("---" + item.data('id'));
    });
});

$("#change").click(function(){
 $("#original_items li")[1].dataset.id = "999";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log">cons</div>
<div id="change">change id</div>
<ul id="original_items">
 <li data-id="1">1</li>
 <li data-id="2">2</li>
 <li data-id="3">3</li>
 <li data-id="4">4</li>
 <li data-id="5">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Все правильно выводит. Код `$("#original_items li")[1].dataset.id = "999";` не меняет data-id. Надо написать `$("#original_items li:nth-child(2)").attr('data-id',999);` У тебя каша в голове из jq и ванилы, в jq нет `dataset` это в ваниле, а в jq либо `attr` либо `data`

Comment: Меняет, это js. Нажмите change id и потом cons

Comment: Это просто чистый javascript, запись тут роли играть не должна. id меняется. Я написал сверху, как можно проверить

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не срабатывает аттрибут data](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488900/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82-data)

Answer (score 1):

Всё прекрасно выводится:

```js
$("button#log").click(e => {
  console.group();
  $("ul li").each(function () {
     console.log("before: ", $(this).data("id"));
  });
  console.groupEnd();
});

$("button#new").click(e => {
  $("ul li").each(function () { // изменить сразу у всех, вдруг пригодится.
    $(this).data("id", Math.random().toString(36));
  });
  console.log("Got new ids");
  
  jQuery($("ul li")[0]).data("id", Math.random().toString(36) + "-dynamic"); // изменить ид кастомного li.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-id="3">Something</li>
  <li data-id="1233">Something</li>
  <li data-id="qwf3">Something</li>
  <li data-id="tqwf3">Something</li>
  <li data-id="wfq3">Something</li>
  <li data-id="qwfqwf3">Something</li>
  <li data-id="wqfqwf3">Something</li>
</ul>
<button id="log">Log ids</button>
<button id="new">Get new IDs.</button>
```

Comment: Приложил сверху пример, чтобы быть конкретнее

Comment: Ваш пример не повторяет проблему, потому что id меняется в процессе вывода. Посмотрите мой пример. Спасибо

Comment: отредактировал пример. проверяйте.

Comment: Вопрос по примеру сверху. Ну в принципе там и ответ написан уже. По крайней мере, предположение.

Answer (score 1):

`data(key,value)` применяется в jQuery для сохранения данных для любого DOM-элемента. Начиная с jQuery 1.4.3 HTML5 серия атрибутов data-* будет автоматически использоваться при использовании объекта данных jQuery. Но помимо этого данные data также хранятся в кэше jQuery. В этом-то и кроется вся хитрость.

Если мы считаем данные атрирута черех `.data()`,а потом поменяем их, использую чистый javascript, в структуре страницы атрибут поменяется, но в кэше останется неизменным и `.data()` выдаст предыдущий атрибут.

Решением будет использовать в коде только jQuery, считывать `data-*` через функцию `.attr()` или через js