# Не считает значение повторно

Tags: jquery

Есть следующий код:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test', function(){
  let i = $(this).data('id'); // получаем значение атрибута
  i++; // значение + 1
  $(this).text(i).attr('data-id', i); // записываем новое значение в атрибут
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test" data-id="0">0</div>
```

Не могу понять одного, почему считает только один раз и как это вылечить?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: @РустамГимранов, т.е. атрибут `data-id`, придётся заменить на какой-нибудь любой не с `data-*`?

Comment: При первом обращении к методу `data()` jQuery считывает атрибуты `data-*` элемента и кэширует. И в дальнейшем использует этот кэш для работы. Вы же изменив один раз `data-*` атрибут в DOM не влияете на этот кэш. Вам нужно определиться: вы работаете или с методом `attr('data-*')` или с методом `.data()`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не срабатывает аттрибут data](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488900/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery не "следит" за изменениями атрибута, поэтому `$(el).data(key)` не изменятся после изменения атрибута

JQuery сохраняет внутри себя значение после первого вызова функции `data`, если необходимо изменить значение, то необходимо вызвать функцию `data` с параметром `value`, `$(el).data(key, value)`, но при этом, в DOM'e не изменится атрибут (при необходимости его можно будет изменить с помощью `$(el).attr(key, value)`)

---

Пример с `$(el).data(key, value)`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test', function(){
  let i = $(this).data('id'); // получаем значение атрибута
  i++; // значение + 1
  $(this).text(i).data('id', i); // записываем новое значение в атрибут
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test" data-id="0">0</div>
```

---

Вы можете работать с атрибутом, без JQ data

Пример без JQ data:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test[data-id]', function(){
  let i = $(this).attr('data-id'); // получаем значение атрибута
  i++; // значение + 1
  $(this).text(i).attr('data-id', i); // записываем новое значение в атрибут
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test" data-id="0">0</div>
```